# Restrict all special characters except for '/' in my input text field in html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to restrict all special characters inside my input text field, except for the character `/`. How do I do that?

Edit: I want my text field to be like this [input text](https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/563/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code did the trick:

```
var specialKeys = new Array();
specialKeys.push(8);  //Backspace
specialKeys.push(9);  //Tab
specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
specialKeys.push(36); //Home
specialKeys.push(35); //End
specialKeys.push(37); //Left
specialKeys.push(39); //Right
     
function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
    //console.log(e.keyCode);
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
    if(e.charCode==47){
        ret=true;
        document.getElementById("error").style.display ="none";
    }
    return ret;
}
```